# How to call a validation function on input tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I am learning angularjs. Here i am faing a problem in validation.

I have a textbox which take input for postcode and after validating it return a true false value.

i have defined the function inside the controller but getting no idea how o call it on textbox

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Postcode" ng-model="myprofile.postCode"  >

.controller("MyProfileCtrl", function ($scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.myprofile = {};
        $scope.myprofile.postCode = "";

        $scope.checkPostCodeError = function(){
            var newPostCode = checkPostCode  ($scope.myprofile.postCode); // calling a javascript function
            if (newPostCode) {
                $scope.myprofile.postCode = newPostCode;
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
  }
```

`checkPostCode` function have different regex pattern it check if math return true else false.

How do i achieve validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is bind the `validate` function to `input`'s event, such as:

```
<input ng-change='checkPostCodeError' or ng-keyup='checkPostCodeError' />
```

Furthermore, you can use `$watch` to watch the `myprofile.postCode` instead.

But, form controls are specially treated in angular. That means angular has many built-in validation function/directives. And you can create your own validation directive.

Here is a demo:

```
app.directive('postCodeValidation', function () {
    function checkPostCodeError(postCode) {
        if(/*your check logic*/) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                if (checkPostCodeError(viewValue)) {
                    // it is valid
                    ctrl.$setValidity('postCode', true);
                    return viewValue;
                } else {
                    // it is invalid, return undefined (no model update)
                    ctrl.$setValidity('postCode', false);
                    return undefined;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});

// how to use in template
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="Postcode" ng-model="myprofile.postCode" name="postCode" post-code-validation/><br /><span ng-show="form.postCode.$error.postCode">This is not valid postCode!</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Why you are using `$parsers` for this? You can use `$validators` instead.

Comment: @RahilWazir `$validators` can also be used.

Comment: @creeper thanks for quick guide i just want to ask that you used post-code-validation but i didn't understant where u declare it as use are creating directive as postCodeValidation

Comment: The `postCodeValidation` is independent of your `MyProfileCtrl`, and it  will check your input: if the value is not valid, your `ng-model="myprofile.postCode"` will be undefined. So, only valid value will be updated to your model.